# Sticky Header for Segmented Control with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to make a page similar to Twitter, which has a profile up top, a segmented control underneath and some cells underneath that. However, I want to have header views too in the section underneath the segmented control. Is there a way I can make it so if I scroll down, the segmented control will be pinned to the top?

It seems that if I use header views below the segmented control, then those headers will replace the segmented control at the top, instead of pinning the segmented control there.

Is this possible to achieve, without doing some serious hacks?

[image]

Picture Source: [How is Twitter profile screen in iOS version built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907271/how-is-twitter-profile-screen-in-ios-version-built)